# PowerShell - Processing Command - Line Parameters In Correct Order

Tags: powershell, command-line

i have an issue regarding the handling of the command - line parameters
within PowerShell:

I have developed a structure to receive the command - line arguments, there are actually 3 Parameters allowed: "-Help", "-Step" and "-Config".

The problem is related to the way the parameters will be processed. In my conception, the script is ALWAYS First checking, if there is a "-Config" Parameter present. Afterwards it should load the Basic Settings and process the "-Step" Parameter last to ensure, that the Config is loaded.

I'm also expecting, that if the user enters the "-Help" Parameter, no matter which Parameter is specified else, the script only will output the Help Dialog.

I really tried to cut the most of the code, but i guess, all parts which are still present are necessary.

If you're executing the script on command line like this:

```
.\AI_Installer.ps1 -Config C:\Scripts\DCT01.cfg -Step Configure_Server -Help
```

the output will be:

```
[ 5 ] Configuring Server Settings ...
[ 1 ] User - Defined Config Found ! [ C:\Scripts\DCT01.cfg ] 0
[ 2 ] The Directory For The User - Defined Config Is Valid ! [ C:\Scripts\DCT01.cfg ]
[ 3 ] User - Defined Config Is Vaild ! [ DCT01.cfg ]
This Is The Help Sector !
[ 4 ] Loading Basic Settings ...
```

I already numbered the steps to make it easier to understand,
what i mean ;)

It would be the best, if i could manually define in "Initialize_Parameters", which parameter will be processed first, second, last etc.

I hope, you unterstand, what i'm trying to do and you're able to provide me a solution for this.

Thanks a lot.

Best regards NumeroUnoDE

Answer (score 1):

A [parameter set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7) can be defined so that a group of parameters are allowed. This is pretty typical in Powershell cmdlets. For example, [Get-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7) allows process name or id, but not both at the same time.

A simple example requires either help or two non-help parameters is like so,

```
function Test-ParameterSets {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'Config')]
        [string]$config,
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ParameterSetName = 'Config')]
        [string]$step,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Help')]
        [switch]$help
    )
    if($config) { "Config section $config $step" }
    if($help) { "Help section $help" }
}

# Call with two valid parameters
Test-ParameterSets -config "config.cfg" -step "step 001"
Config section config.cfg step 001

# Call with one valid parameters
Test-ParameterSets -help                                                                               
Help section True

# Call with invalid parameters (no help and others)
Test-ParameterSets -config "config.cfg" -step "step 001" -help                                         Test-ParameterSets : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

# Call with missing parameter
Test-ParameterSets -config "config.cfg"
cmdlet Test-ParameterSets at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
step:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Global_Switches = $args

$Global_Switches_Store = @{ }
$Global_Switches_Values_Store = @( )

$AI_Identifier = $myInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

$AI_Server_Config = @{ }

$AI_Debug_Mode = "Yes"
```

```
function Initialize 
{
    if( !( $Global_Switches ) )
    {
        $Global_Switches_Store[ '-Step' ] = @( "Configure_Server" )
        Load_Basic_Settings
        Selector
    }

        if( $Global_Switches )
    {
        Initialize_Parameters
        Selector
        Load_Basic_Settings
    }
}
```

```
function Initialize_Parameters
{
    $Global_Switches_Entries = $Global_Switches.Count

    $Global_Switches_Parameter

    for( $Global_Switches_Counter = 0; $Global_Switches_Counter -lt $Global_Switches_Entries; $Global_Switches_Counter++ )
    {
        if( $Global_Switches[ $Global_Switches_Counter ].Contains( "-" ) )
        {
            if( !( $Global_Switches_Store.Contains( $Global_Switches[ $Global_Switches_Counter ] ) ) )
            {
                $Global_Switches_Values = @( )
                $Global_Switches_Parameter = $Global_Switches[ $Global_Switches_Counter ]               
            
            } else {
                        Write-Host "The Parameter '$( $Global_Switches[ $Global_Switches_Counter ] )' Already Exists !"
                   }
    
        } else {
                    $Global_Switches_Values += $Global_Switches[ $Global_Switches_Counter ]           
               }

        if( $Global_Switches_Parameter )
        {
            $Global_Switches_Store[ $Global_Switches_Parameter ] = $Global_Switches_Values
        }
    }
}
```

```
function Selector {
    
    $Available_Switches = @( "-Config" , "-Help" , "-Step" )
    
    foreach( $Switches_Parameter in $Global_Switches_Store.Keys )
    {
        if( $Available_Switches.Contains( $Switches_Parameter ) )
        {
            if( $Switches_Parameter -eq "-Config" )
            {
                $Switches_Values_Entries = $Global_Switches_Store[ $Switches_Parameter ].Count

                if( $Switches_Values_Entries -eq 0 ) { Write-Host "Need Values For Parameter '$Switches_Parameter' !"  ; exit }         
                if( $Switches_Values_Entries -gt 1 ) { Write-Host "Only One Value Allowed For Parameter '$Switches_Parameter' !"  ; exit  }
                
                $IMWS_Config_User_Defined = $Global_Switches_Store[ $Switches_Parameter ]
                Write-Host "[ 1 ] User - Defined Config Found ! [ $IMWS_Config_User_Defined ]" 0  

                if( Test-Path $IMWS_Config_User_Defined )
                {
                    Write-Host "[ 2 ] The Directory For The User - Defined Config Is Valid ! [ $IMWS_Config_User_Defined ]"
                    
                    $Config_File_Handler = Split-Path $IMWS_Config_User_Defined -leaf
                    $Config_File_EXTN = [IO.Path]::GetExtension( $Config_File_Handler )
                     
                    if( $Config_File_EXTN -ne ".cfg" )
                    {
                        Write-Host "[ 3 ] User - Defined Config Is Not Vaild ! [ $Config_File_Handler ]"                        
                        exit
                    
                    } else {                         
                             Write-Host "[ 3 ] User - Defined Config Is Vaild ! [ $Config_File_Handler ]" 
                           }
                                    
                } else {
                             Write-Host "[ 2 ] User - Defined Config Not Found ! [ $IMWS_Config_User_Defined ]"
                             exit
                       }
           }

            if( $Switches_Parameter -eq "-Help" )
                    {
                 Write-Host "This Is The Help Sector !"
            }
            
            if( $Switches_Parameter -eq "-Step" )
                    {
                        $Switches_Values_Entries = $Global_Switches_Store[ $Switches_Parameter ].Count

                        if( $Switches_Values_Entries -eq 0 )
                        {                  
                            Write-Host "Need Values For Parameter '$Switches_Parameter' !"     
                    # exit
                        }

                        if( $Switches_Values_Entries -gt 1 )
                        {
                             Write-Host "Only One Value Allowed For Parameter '$Switches_Parameter' !" 
                    # exit
                        }
           
                        $Switches_Parameters = $Global_Switches_Store[ $Switches_Parameter ]
                
                        for( $Switches_Values_Counter = 0; $Switches_Values_Counter -lt $Switches_Values_Entries; $Switches_Values_Counter++ )
                        {
                    $Switches_Values = $Switches_Parameters[ $Switches_Values_Counter ]
                    if( $Switches_Values -eq "Configure_Server" ) { Configure_Server }
                        }
                    }
    
        } else {
                   Write-Host "Wrong Parameter '$Switches_Parameter' !"
               }
    }
}
```